# Dilemma about the number of columns on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Scenario:
I am creating a website for a checklist, it can be done/accessed by multiple users in the same time  thus it needs certain fields to be editable, saveable and retrievable.

Dilemma:
The checklist has 212 entries, this means 212 rows. I have 5 columns that needs entries thus, 212x5. This means, I have to create 1060 columns to be able for me to code the website to do what I want it to do. 1060 columns on a table seems wrong and very tiring to use.

My Sample solution:
I would divide the 5 columns into 5 tables, making the date that the checklist was created as their primary key. I would then use this 5 tables for their corresponding columns thus reducing the number of columns per table to 212.

Is there anyway that I could reduce this? Sorry for the long post, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: For some reason, I can't comment on any answers, says error on page. Nevertheless, I do appreciate everybody's answer; Yet I have 1 info that may change your answers. I have thought of making 5 columns instead of the obnoxious 1060, but doing that, I would need/The system would need to create 1 table per 1 worksheet and of course, over time, this would cause massive problems to the database.
Although still pretty huge, ah_hau's answer seems to be the smallest and easiest to handle. By using it, the system would create 217 entries per checklist, but will use 6-8 columns only. Thank you to everyone who shed light into this dillemma, I do hope that I see you guys again on my next question. *Cheers!*

Comment: couldn't you simply make a table in DB with 6 column(PK+5columns) and 212 rows...? or should i ask, why do you think every field in your check list need its seperate column?

Comment: Because every cell on those 5 columns will contain a textbox therefore there will be some data that needs to be retrievable. There will be 1(new) checklist everyday that is why I created the table with the creation date as its primary key.

Comment: Your logic seems a bit flawed--212 rows * 5 columns = 1060 *cells*, not columns. That's definitely not too many for any database. But yes, 1060 columns is *definitely* more than you want.

Comment: I'm with Matthew. If the key of the checklist is the date... and you have 212 entries, then you should have with 212 rows per day, with a key of date and entry... plus 5 columns to hold the 5 values. Check ah_hau's answer that just popped up.

Comment: What does each column stand for? If they're related, you should consider extracting them out into another table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why not directly add 1 more column in your checklist table?

your table structure should look like

1. userid
2. entryid (value from 1-212)
3. col1_entry
4. col2_entry
5. col3_entry
6. col4_entry
7. col5_entry

Comment: based on your new requirement, you might add another day column to fit your request

Comment: @ruthermelchor, you may also add column worksheetid or checklistid, multiple table is not recommended unless your data volume is really huge.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it, I'd just store a Json string per checklist. The Json string would be a Json array of object { checklistName, checklistValue, timestamp }. So, the database table would only have two columns { id, checklist }. This is on the minimum side, you might want to break it down to smaller Json objects and/or add more details to them.

Answer (score 0):

looking thrrough all your requirements, thou you've ban the common 6 column setup, I'd still suggest you to use a similar setup.

try to have a table like this

```
id [bigInt] (PK,auto_incrment)
rowId [int] //checklist row id
columnId [int] //checklist column id
text [varchar/text]
create_date [Date]
create_time [Time]

Index
unique key chekcklist_cell (create_date, rowId, columnId)
```

depending on your preference, you could also split `columnId` field into 5 columns with name `column1~5` to reduce the DB entry count. But i'd suggest using my setup as it seems like user will update your checklist 1 cell at a time (or multiple cell all around the list), which my schema will make more sense. Also this schema is very expandable and could easily add new fields to them. Last thing I could think of is that you doesn't have to lock the whole checklist while a user is only updating 1 cell. This helps speed up that concurrent access thing.